Why is concatenation in log4j prone to attacks?
Here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/getting-started.html#best-practice-concat
They say this about using string concatenation in log4j:

More importantly, this approach is prone to attacks! Imagine userId
being provided by the user with the following content: placeholders
for non-existing args to trigger failure: {} {} {dangerousLookup}

Could someone explain why this is dangerous? I don't get what string concatenation has to do with this "dangerousLookup" thing.

What the documentation is trying to tell here is that log4j will evaluate various expressions within the format string (e.g. ${env:SECRET_ENV_VAR}). So you should not concatenate anything you don't control to it.

@Violet: since 2.15.0 expressions in the format string are not evaluated.

I think the documentation is very clear

Imagine userId being provided by the user with the following content:
placeholders for non-existing args to trigger failure: {} {}

In case you have the following logger and you pass the above userId
LOGGER.info("failed for user ID: " + userId);

The code execution will break since the logger will have as content the "failed for user ID: placeholders for non-existing args to trigger failure: {} {} " and the logger will throw an exception that the 2 arguments which are required, are not provided.
Also as the commenter Violet mentioned someone could even pass an argument with concatenation which is evaluated dynamically. Something that should not be printed in the logs, e.g ${env:SECRET_ENV_VAR} which is the case mentioned for dangerous lookup.
You can also combine the above two for example and see how someone could use a thrown exception from a logger that provides information for the exception to the user to get information that should be otherwise hidden.
This is why they advice as requirement that the layout of the message is concrete and not in control of the argument. E.g.
LOGGER.info("failed for user ID `{}`", userId);

Now the logger will just print the provided argument userId as described in the layout and will not mix it with the layout so that you are protected from the above and several other issues.

In certain circumstances you can even refer to JNDI and load classes from remote machine.

@talexmovedtoCodidact: Log4Shell did affect string concatenation and parameterized logging equally.

@Panagiotis Bougioukos: The throwing behavior for a mismatch in the number of parameters briefly appeared in version 2.23.0 of Log4j Core and was replaced by a warning in version 2.23.1 (see release notes).

The documentation is confusing, thanks for reporting the problem.
Both string concatenation and parameterized logging alone do not have security implications. A problem appears, however, when you mix the two:
logger.warn("Login failed for user '" + user + "' from remote address '{}'.", remoteIp);

If the attacker sends {} as user, you will get a message like:
Login failed for user '192.0.2.1' from remote address '{}'.

This is a mild log injection vulnerability, but it can cause problems for automatic log parsers or confuse administrators. If you use parameterized logging, the format string should be a compile-time constant.
Such a problem will not appear if you only use string concatenation or parameterized logging:
// String concatenation
logger.warn("Login failed for user '" + user + "' from remote address '" + remoteIp + "'.");
// Parameterized logging
logger.warn("Login failed for user '{}' from remote address '{}'.", user, remoteIp);

which will both return:
Login failed for user '{}' from remote address '192.0.2.1'.

Note: If the log files are automatically parsed and the parameters of log messages have a meaning, it is recommended to use a structured logging layout together with map messages.

If you use string concatenation as in the example you linked, and the value of the variable you're concatenating can come from an external source that you may not control, an attacker can make that value have placeholders that the logging method from log4j will process as normal and that can contain malicious code that exploits a vulnerability in log4j. That malicious code would then be executed and the attacker would gain the benefits of exploiting that vulnerability. That's what the {dangerouslookup} means, presumably referring to past vulnerabilities in log4j that used JNDI lookups as an attack vector.
